# Problems with BroadcastReceiver to detect connection or disconnection to Internet

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, connection-leaks

The aim is to implement a **BroadcastReceiver** within my Android App that dynamically detects when the device changes its status of connection or disconnection to the Internet. I have tried with several tutorials and solution proposals, but I still don't manage to make it work correctly, and I always get the same: "*leaked IntentReceiver*" error.

The relevant code is:
 First, I write a class derived from the **BroadcastReceiver** class:

```
public class InternetConnector_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   public InternetConnector_Receiver() {}

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      try {
             boolean isVisible = MyApplication.isActivityVisible();// Check if activity is visible or not
             Log.i("Activity is Visible ", "Is activity visible : " + isVisible);

             // If it is visible then trigger the task else do nothing
                if (isVisible == true) {
                   ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                   NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                   // Check internet connection and accrding to state change then text of activity by calling method
                   if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                      new LMMoviesMainActivity().TTSstatusDataNetChanged(true);
                   } else {
                      new LMMoviesMainActivity().TTSstatusDataNetChanged(false);
                   }
                }
     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
}
```

Then, I create the related variables in the LMMoviesMainActivity.

**Question:** Do the 3 Actions added to the **IntentFilter** correctly activate the detection of connection to the Internet? If they are incorrect, what are the right values?

```
private IntentFilter internetConnectionGloIntentFilter;
private InternetConnector_Receiver objGloInternetConnectorReceiver;
internetConnectionGloIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
internetConnectionGloIntentFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
internetConnectionGloIntentFilter.addAction("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED");
internetConnectionGloIntentFilter.addAction("android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE");
objGloInternetConnectorReceiver = new InternetConnector_Receiver();
registerReceiver(objGloInternetConnectorReceiver, internetConnectionGloIntentFilter);
```

Finally, the function that contains the instructions to execute when a change in Internet connection occurs:

```
public void TTSstatusDataNetChanged(boolean isConnectedBool) {
   unregisterReceiver(objGloInternetConnectorReceiver);
   registerReceiver(objGloInternetConnectorReceiver, internetConnectionGloIntentFilter);

   // Change status according to boolean value
   if (isConnectedBool) {

      if (ttsSettingsGloDialog.isShowing()) {
         ttsWarningsGloTextView.setText( "Net ON" );
      }

      dataNetConnectedGloBool = true;
   } else {

      if (ttsSettingsGloDialog.isShowing()) {
         ttsWarningsGloTextView.setText( "Net Off" );
      }

      dataNetConnectedGloBool = false;
   }
}
```

Trying to execute: **unregisterReceiver**, I get the message:

*Service com.google.android.youtube.api.service.YouTubeService has leaked IntentReceiver wuq@3967361 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?*

But I guess that I must unregister the Receiver, and then register it again, to be ready for the next connection event, right? If the current unregisterReceiver is not referring to the intent or event triggered, then how to correctly write the instruction and associate it?

I checked in the debugger that the Intent triggers, and the **BroadcastReceiver** receives the event, but I just don't know how to overcome this leaked error. Any ideas? Am I missing something crucial? Do you see any mistake? Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

Unregister ur receiver `objGloInternetConnectorReceiver`in the `OnDestroy()` callback of ur LMMoviesMainActivity

```
 @Override
     protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();

          unregisterReceiver(objGloInternetConnectorReceiver);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. A question: Do I have to execute: **registerReceiver** again? (for the next event of change in the Internet connection). If so, where do I need to place the **registerReceiver** command?

Comment: register receiver in on create  and unregister in onDestroy that's all

Comment: or u can do in the way @Anonymous suggested or my way both works fine

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your code. You do not need to check if the Activity is visible if you register the receiver in `onResume()` and unregister it in `onPause()`.

```
if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    new LMMoviesMainActivity().TTSstatusDataNetChanged(true);
} else {
    new LMMoviesMainActivity().TTSstatusDataNetChanged(false);
}
```

That won't work because you need to reference the actual Activity and not a new one. If you put the BroadcastReceiver in LMMoviesMainActivity just do

```
if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    LMMoviesMainActivity.this.TTSstatusDataNetChanged(true);
} else {
    LMMoviesMainActivity.this.TTSstatusDataNetChanged(false);
}
```

Also you do not have to unregister and register a new Broadcastreceiver when you received a broadcast. So remove these lines:

```
unregisterReceiver(objGloInternetConnectorReceiver);
registerReceiver(objGloInternetConnectorReceiver, internetConnectionGloIntentFilter);
```

Here a complete example that should work: (Dont forget to initialize ttsSettingsGloDialog, ttsWarningsGloTextView and dataNetConnectedGloBool)

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LMMoviesMainActivity extends Activity {

    private IntentFilter internetConnectionGloIntentFilter;
    private InternetConnector_Receiver objGloInternetConnectorReceiver;

    private Dialog ttsSettingsGloDialog;
    private TextView ttsWarningsGloTextView;
    private boolean dataNetConnectedGloBool;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        internetConnectionGloIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        internetConnectionGloIntentFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
        internetConnectionGloIntentFilter.addAction("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED");
        internetConnectionGloIntentFilter.addAction("android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE");

        objGloInternetConnectorReceiver = new InternetConnector_Receiver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(objGloInternetConnectorReceiver, internetConnectionGloIntentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(objGloInternetConnectorReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void TTSstatusDataNetChanged(boolean isConnectedBool) {
        // Change status according to boolean value
        if (isConnectedBool) {

            if (ttsSettingsGloDialog.isShowing()) {
                ttsWarningsGloTextView.setText( "Net ON" );
            }

            dataNetConnectedGloBool = true;
        } else {

            if (ttsSettingsGloDialog.isShowing()) {
                ttsWarningsGloTextView.setText( "Net Off" );
            }

            dataNetConnectedGloBool = false;
        }
    }

    public class InternetConnector_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            try {
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                // Check internet connection and accrding to state change then text of activity by calling method
                if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    LMMoviesMainActivity.this.TTSstatusDataNetChanged(true);
                } else {
                    LMMoviesMainActivity.this.TTSstatusDataNetChanged(false);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to Mr. Mark Sitro. I implemented your solution and it works! That left me wondering why the InternetConnector_Receiver implemented as an external class does not work: it does trigger the Intent when there is connection or disconnection to Internet, but it always generates the **leaked IntentReceiver** error. Maybe I am breaching some rule in OO Programming or in Java / Android itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register for broadcast reciever only once instead of registering every time.Everytime when you register for a broadcast reciever you have to unregister it.Registering every time inside the method is causing the leak.Remove it and register only in onResume and unregister in onPause.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(objGloInternetConnectorReceiver, internetConnectionGloIntentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(objGloInternetConnectorReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```